# Attempting to read from a COM port crashes the JVM

Tags: java, serial-port

I'm trying to read in some data from a COM port. But I am getting a response "9", but I wrote one s.o.p like `System.out.println("This is i/p stream")`. Instead of this I get a fatal error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: eis
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
    at gnu.io.RXTXPort.readByte(Native Method)
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x10009775, pid=3048, tid=2188
#
# JRE version: 6.0_24-b07
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (19.1-b02 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [rxtxSerial.dll+0x9775]
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# D:\Manly\PCMC\hs_err_pid3048.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
    at gnu.io.RXTXPort$SerialInputStream.read(RXTXPort.java:1250)
#
    at pcmc.PCMC.send(PCMC.java:136)
    at pcmc.PCMC.main(PCMC.java:189)
Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1
```

---

```
 package pcmc;



import gnu.io.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class PCMC implements  SerialPortEventListener
{
    Enumeration portList;
    CommPortIdentifier portId;
    SerialPort serialPort;
    DataInputStream dis;
    OutputStream outputStream;
    InputStream inputStream;
    Thread readThread;

     String messageString;
     String messageString1;
 static PCMC f;
     String strResponse="";
     PCMC pWriter;
     String msg[]=new String[200];
     int ix=0;

     boolean msgEnd=true;

    String className;
     static Enumeration ports;
    static CommPortIdentifier pID;
    static String messageToSend = "ComPortSendMsg deatails!\n";


    public PCMC(String className) throws NoSuchPortException, IOException, TooManyListenersException
    {

            this.className=className;
            //portList =  CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
           ports = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
         System.out.println("ports name"+ports);
        while(ports.hasMoreElements())
        {
            pID = (CommPortIdentifier)ports.nextElement();
            System.out.println("Port Name " + pID.getName());

            if (pID.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL)
            {
                System.out.println("Port Name 1 " + pID.getName());
                if (pID.getName().equals("COM1"))
                {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Port Name 2 " + pID.getName());
                         System.out.println("COM1 found");
                         serialPort=(SerialPort)pID.open(className, 1000);

                         outputStream=serialPort.getOutputStream();

                         inputStream=serialPort.getInputStream();
                     //    dis=new DataInputStream(inputStream);
                          //f.serialEvent1(inputStream);
                         //serialPort.addEventListener(this);
                         break;
                    } catch (PortInUseException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(PCMC.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }


                }
            }
        }

        //outputStream.write(messageToSend.getBytes());





    }

      public void closePort()
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println((char)13);
            inputStream.close();
            System.out.println("Finished2");
            outputStream.close();
            System.out.println("Finished1");

            serialPort.close();
            System.out.println("Finished");


        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Close Error"+e);
        }


    }


    public void send(String phno,String msg)
    {
String s = "AT+CMGF="+1+"\n";
  int data;
        String r;
        byte[] buffer=new byte[1000];
s+=(char)13;
System.out.println("AT+CMGF command :"+s);

       messageString = "AT+CMGS=\""+phno+"\"\r";
        messageString1 = msg+"\n" +(char)26;
        System.out.println("AT CMGS "+messageString);
        System.out.println("AT CMGS  "+messageString1);

        try
        {
            outputStream.write(s.getBytes());
            //outputStream.notifyAll();
            Thread.sleep(1000);

           System.out.println(inputStream.available()+" : ramdn : ");

          //  System.out.println(dis.readInt()+" : radsgas : ");

        try
        {
            int len = 0;
            while ( ( data = inputStream.read())!= -1 )
            {
                System.out.println("This is i/p stream");
                buffer[len++] = (byte) data;
            }
            r = new String(buffer,0,len);
            System.out.println("this is input stream msg"+r);
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }






           System.out.print("this is send try block");


        }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
           System.out.println(e);
          }



    }



        public static void main(String args[]) throws NoSuchPortException, IOException, TooManyListenersException
        {

            PCMC f=new PCMC("Msg Sending");

            try {
                f.send("9994106650","Wish U Happy New Year in advance.");
               // f.send("9884345649","Wish U Happy New Year in advance.");
                Thread.sleep(1000);

                 //  f.send("9597502571","Good Bye..");
                 //  f.send("9597502571","Good Bye..");
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(PCMC.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
          //  }


            System.out.println("---------END--------");

              //f.deleteAll();

            f.closePort();


        }






       }

    @Override
    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent spe) {

            int data;
        String r;
        byte[] buffer=new byte[1000];
        try
        {
            int len = 0;
            while ( ( data = inputStream.read()) > -1 )
            {
                buffer[len++] = (byte) data;
            }
            r = new String(buffer,0,len);
            System.out.println("this is input stream msg"+r);
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }





}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things may be wrong in this code.

First, the error log doesn't seem to match the code: from the error log, PCMC.java:189 should be a call to send(), but seems to be a blank line instead.  Is the code you posted exactly the code that you ran to cause the error?

Guessing about the version of this code that caused the error, I think the problem may have been reentrancy in inputstream.read().  If the PCMC constructor registered itself via serialPort.addEventListener(this), then the following sequence could occur:

1. Main calls PCMC.send(), which writes a message, then blocks in send's inputstream.read().
2. Serial input data becomes available.  RXTX wants to call PCMC.serialEvent(), but it's blocked in inputstream.read().  Bad things then happen.

To successfully use RXTX, the code should either do I/O inside serialEvent(), or must not be a listener, and must do conventional blocking I/O.  If you try to read from the serial port in both your main sequence and inside serialEvent(), RXTX will likely break.

A third thing I noticed: one version of the code you posted may have attempted to close the serial port without first unregistering itself as a listener.  If you call addEventListener(), you should unregister that listener before calling close() on the port.

Again, all of my notes are guesses about the version of your code that actually generated the error log in the post.  In the future, please make sure to post the same version of the code that produced the error.  Apologies if I mistakenly thought the code didn't match the error log - and good luck!

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar error. I solved it by replacing `librxtxSerial.so` by the one found at http://jlog.org/rxtx-lin.html